# stdin read notification

Tags: io, stdin

I want to detect when/if an application issues `read(stdin, ...)`. Is it possible to use unbuffered I/O so that I could wait on write in external process?

The problem:

Some commands require user input when executed, I want to detect those and handle them because I'm targeting headless environment.

I'm also thinking whether the task isn't too broad and that the usage of `read(stdin, ..)` is simply too generic and not limited to requesting user input, what other set of constraints would also apply? I can think of:

- Perform these checks only if the `stdin` hasn't been redirected to allow for `|` piping
- Prompts are usually reading entire lines (have to press enter), so maybe try write a single char

Or is the input discarded without blocking if the application is not `read(stdin, ...)` at the moment the input is sent (that's just my rationale for `yes` spamming `y\n` in the terminal)?

Comment: If the goal is to feed the program appropriate input when it tries to read it, it's difficult to detect which piece of code in the program is doing the read. In general, you'd rely on the program first printing out something that says what sort of input it wants. And that's how the [expect](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) program does its job.

Comment: You could try using a named pipe, and redirect standard input from that. Reads will then block until something writes to the pipe. I just don't understand what you mean with `yes`, the sole purpose of that tool is to send endless repeats of `y\n` (or whatever else) to its standard output.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick thanks for the link for expect. The goal is sole detection that the application is requesting input from stdin (which cannot be satisfied because it's headless).

Comment: @wurtel I'll take a look into named pipes, thanks. About `yes` - my train of assumptions has crashed, disregard that remark :)